# get past user actions

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I have a jsp page. In the page i have got 3 radio button. When I click the button a url is send to action servlet and the same page is reloaded again. But when the new page reloads again the radio button which i checked earlier is unchecked . I want to to somehow remember and check it again so that when the page reloads the user can see what radio button he clicked as there are three radio buttons and all do same page reloading. Any suggestions how i can accomplish this..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JSP/Struts, but this is how I do it in PHP. You may be able to convert it to JSP code:

```
<form method="POST">
<?php
    // labels for our radio buttons
    $labels = array('Value 0', 'Value 1', 'Value 2');

    // get the submitted value, or set to -1
    $radio = (isset($_POST['radio']) ? (int)$_POST['radio'] : -1);

    // loop for each label
    for ($r=0; $r<count($labels); $r++) {

        // if current iteration matches submitted value, check the radio
        $checked = ($radio == $r ? 'CHECKED' : '');

        // output radio button and label
        echo <<< HTML
    <input type="radio"  id="radio{$r}"  name="radio" value="{$r}" {$checked}>
    <label for="radio{$r}"> {$labels[$r]}</label>
HTML;
    }
?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this. I'll give an example to do this. I'm not really good with this but you can improve my coding. Here it is;

I assume you already know how to send request to server and forward it.

index.jsp

```
    <%
        int chkOpt = 0;
        if(request.getAttribute("checked") != null){
            chkOpt = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("checked").toString());  
        }
    %>

<form action="reload" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="1" <% if(chkOpt == 1) out.print("CHECKED"); %> />First Radio Button
<input type="radio" name="option" value="2" <% if(chkOpt == 2) out.print("CHECKED"); %> />Second Radio Button
<input type="radio" name="option" value="3" <% if(chkOpt == 3) out.print("CHECKED"); %> />Third Radio Button
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Reload Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String optval = null;
    if(request.getParameter("option") != null){
        optval = request.getParameter("option").toString(); 
    }

    request.setAttribute("checked", optval);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);b
}
```

The main things here is that you have a variable that will handle which option was clicked.

I hope you got my point base on my example. This is already working just take a try and understand how it do. Note: this only jsp and servlet

Comment: I wonder how, what the minus for? anyway I answered this to the best of my knowledge. I hope someone will post the best answer so I may refer to it, to improve my programming techniques and skills.